# Replacing values in xts object avoiding subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have an `xts` object

```
library(xts)
A <- xts(c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA), Sys.Date()-11:1)
colnames(A) <- c("A")
```

What I need is: every time we observe a 1 in A, then

1. The next two days should contain also a 1 (the next day here means the next row).
2. The third day after we observe a 1 should be a zero.

So the result should look like

```
> A
              A
2014-12-28    1
2014-12-29    1
2014-12-30    1
2014-12-31    0
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-02    1
2015-01-03    1
2015-01-04    0
2015-01-05   NA
2015-01-06    1
2015-01-07    1
```

What I have tried is

```
dates.with.1 <- which(A==1)
A[dates.with.1 + 1] <- 1
A[dates.with.1 + 2] <- 1
A[dates.with.1 + 3] <- 0
```

Which gives me

```
Error in `[.xts`(x, i, which.i = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds
```

since adding the second 1 is not possible at the end of A.

Comment: Sure, `dates.with.1 + 2` gives 3,7 and 12. The last value is out the bounds of `A`, which is of length 11.

Comment: Yes I know. That is the Problem... Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works if `A` consists only of `1`s and `NA`s, as is given in the toy exaple.

```
pmax(pmax(A,lag(A),lag(A,2),na.rm=TRUE), lag(A-A,3), na.rm=TRUE)
#            A
#2014-12-28  1
#2014-12-29  1
#2014-12-30  1
#2014-12-31  0
#2015-01-01  1
#2015-01-02  1
#2015-01-03  1
#2015-01-04  0
#2015-01-05 NA
#2015-01-06  1
#2015-01-07  1
```